# Maven add WorldEdit Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, bukkit

How can I add this WorldEdit dependency to my Maven project?
http://maven.sk89q.com/artifactory/repo/com/sk89q/worldedit/worldedit-bukkit/
I need the 6.1.1-SNAPSHOT.

Is there an algorithm to get 
Group ID
Artifact ID 
and Version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important you understand the task at hand. Maven downloads *dependencies* from remote *repositories* based on their unique *coordinates*. There are two kind of repositories:

- release repositories that host release versions of dependencies, i.e. final versions.
- snapshot repositories that host snapshot versions of dependencies, i.e. versions that are currently in development, and are not stable yet.

A Maven coordinate is a set `(groupId, artifactId, version)`. It uniquely identifies every dependency (truth be told, there are actually a packaging and a possibly a classifier but it's not important here).

Your problem is to declare a dependency to the `worldedit-bukkit-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT` dependency. Let's see:

- the repository here is `http://maven.sk89q.com/artifactory/repo`: it is the root of the URL you linked to.
- the groupId is `com.sk89q.worldedit`: this is the rest of the URL, right before
- the artifactId, which is `worldedit-bukkit` and
- the version, which is `6.1.1-SNAPSHOT`.

If you breakdown the URL, you get

```
http://maven.sk89q.com/artifactory/repo/com/sk89q/worldedit/worldedit-bukkit/6.1.1-SNAPSHOT/
```

that is translated into the following Maven coordinates:

```
{REPOSITORY_URL}/{groupId where dots are slashes}/{artifactId}/{version}/
```

So now, we need to tell Maven about the repository. By default, Maven looks for artifacts in what's called [Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/), so we need to add this repository. This is done either in the POM or in the `settings.xml` file, by adding the [following configuration](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories):

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>sk89q-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://maven.sk89q.com/artifactory/repo</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled> <!-- releases enabled: this specific repository also hosts release versions -->
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled> <!-- snapshots enabled: we declare a SNAPSHOT repository because we need to download a SNAPSHOT dependency -->
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Next step is to actually declare the dependency. This is done in the POM, with the following configuration:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sk89q.worldedit</groupId>
  <artifactId>worldedit-bukkit</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

And that's it!

Comment: oh thanks your awsome ... thats exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Where did you find `sk89q-snapshots` ?